# Convert string columns into numeric columns with SQL in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm analyzing the [data of New York City taxi trips of yellow cars in 2018](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018). (You need a Google BigQuery account to access this data set.)

The schema says that most of the columns are numeric. However, when I tried to calculate the sum of the key dollar figures (tip_amount, tolls_amount, total_amount), I got an error message saying that they are string variables.

```
SELECT sum(total_amount) 
FROM [bigquery-public-data:new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018] 
WHERE month(dropoff_datetime) = 12

Error: Field total_amount is of type STRING which is not supported for SUM
```

I then tried to use the cast() function to convert it to a numeric variable, but that did not work.

```
SELECT sum(total_amount_numeric) FROM 
(
     SELECT cast(total_amount as numeric) as total_amount_numeric 
     FROM [bigquery-public-data:new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018]
     WHERE month(dropoff_datetime) = 12
)

Error: Field total_amount_numeric is of type STRING which is not supported for SUM
```

How can I analyze these numeric variables as I intended, instead of the string variables as they are erroneously set in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT SUM(total_amount) 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018`
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dropoff_datetime) = 12
```

The problem you had is because NUMERIC data type is not supported by BigQuery Legacy SQL and rather is treated as STRING and cannot CAST to neither FLOAT nor INTEGER

So, the workaround is to use BigQuery Standard SQL as in above example -  and as you see here you don't need to do any CAST'ing as this field is already NUMERIC

Answer (score 1):

Your query will run as follows in Standard SQL:

```
SELECT sum(total_amount_numeric)  
FROM (SELECT cast(total_amount as numeric) as total_amount_numeric 
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_taxi_trips.tlc_yellow_trips_2018`
      WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM dropoff_datetime) = 12
     ) x;
```

You can include this hint before the query to ensure that it is run using standard SQL:

```
#standardSQL
```

Comment: What's the "x" before your semi-colon?

Thanks for this solution. It works!

Comment: @Iterator516 . . . It is a table alias.

Comment: Ah, yes. You did not use this alias in the above query, but you can refer to this table later in another query. Am I right?

Comment: @Iterator516 . . . I am in the habit of always providing an alias for a subquery in the `FROM` clause, even in databases that do not require it.  I generally qualify table names, but a sometimes lax in queries that refer to only one table, once.